# printf or similar inside an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, printf

I saw a similar question but no answers yet.

I have the following SQL query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM patient_db_0004 WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) AGAINST ('$term' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

where patient_db_0004 is I want to print an auto increment index like "0001,0002,0003,0004" inside my SQL query.

```
printf("%04s",$i);
```

To print the values inside the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MySQL you can use the [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html). For your example, you might want to try [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
SELECT LPAD(`id`, 4, '0') FROM patient_db_0004
```

You could search for similar functions for your database engine.

Sample output:

```
mysql> SELECT LPAD(`id` , 4, '0') FROM `patient_db_0004` LIMIT 10;
+---------------------+
| LPAD(`id` , 4, '0') |
+---------------------+
| 0001                |
| 0002                |
| 0003                |
| 0004                |
| 0005                |
| 0006                |
| 0007                |
| 0008                |
| 0009                |
| 0010                |
+---------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(I've got an auto_increment field called `id` in the above example)

**Edit:** based on your comment, it seems [Vincent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266031/printf-or-similar-inside-an-sql-query/7266039#7266039) is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$term = 'foobar';
for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo(sprintf("SELECT * FROM patient_db_%04d WHERE MATCH (Name, id_number) AGAINST ('$term' IN BOOLEAN MODE);\n", $i));
}
?>
```

Gave me:

```
SELECT * FROM patient_db_0001 WHERE MATCH (Name, id_number) AGAINST ('foobar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM patient_db_0002 WHERE MATCH (Name, id_number) AGAINST ('foobar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM patient_db_0003 WHERE MATCH (Name, id_number) AGAINST ('foobar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
SELECT * FROM patient_db_0004 WHERE MATCH (Name, id_number) AGAINST ('foobar' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If I understand correctly, you are trying to run these queries. So what you might consider doing here is:

```
<?php
// ...
for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
{
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM patient_db_%04d WHERE MATCH (Name, id_number) AGAINST ('$term' IN BOOLEAN MODE);\n", $i);
    $sql = mysql_query();
}
?>
```

Comment: so I can SELECT FROM 'patient_db_0004', patient_db_0005, patient_db_0006 - automatically?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I've edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) instead of printf (which prints the value to the string) :

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = '%s'", "hi");
$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

However, keep in mind that this does not prevent you from SQL injections. You still have to use mysql_real_escape_string on user-provided data.